# Jenkins Job DSL: Creating parameter object in function

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I want to write a function (in a jenkins job DSL) which returns a reusable set of parameters for job defintions. Like this:

```
def pars(name) {
  return parameters {
        booleanParam(name, true)
  }
}

pipelineJob("Test1") {
  pars("name")
}
pipelineJob("Test2") {
  pars("name2")
}
```

This does not work, but can I somehow rewrite the example so that it does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parameters` can not be called in your helper method, but you can create a closure in a helper method.

Try this:

```
def pars(name) {
  return {
    booleanParam(name, true)
  }
}

pipelineJob("Test1") {
  parameters pars("name")
}
```

Or this:

```
def pars(name) {
  return {
    parameters {
      booleanParam(name, true)
    }
  }
}

pipelineJob("Test1").with pars("name")
```